# Dickson/determinant type polynomial (updated)

Tags: co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, algebraic-combinatorics, schur-functions

For $2\leq \ell \leq k$, consider the polynomial \begin{equation} P_{k,\ell} = \prod_{1\leq a_1+\ldots+a_k\leq \ell} (a_1x_1+\ldots + a_kx_k)\in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,\ldots, x_k] \end{equation}

consisting of all products of all non-zero linear forms $a_1x_1+\ldots +a_kx_k$, at most $\ell$ of whose coefficients are non-zero.

Now let \begin{equation} \alpha_j = \sum_{i=0}^{\ell-1}\binom{j-1}{i}, \end{equation}

and

\begin{equation} D_{k,\ell}= \det \begin{pmatrix} x_1^{\alpha_1} & \cdots & x_k^{\alpha_1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_1^{\alpha_k} & \cdots & x_k^{\alpha_k} \end{pmatrix} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} x_{\sigma(1)}^{\alpha_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_{\sigma(k)}^{\alpha_k},  \end{equation}

where $S_k$ is the symmetric group.

(Note that $\alpha_{1}=1$, and we assume as usual that $\binom{a}{b}=0$ if $a<b$.)

**Question**: It is a classical fact that $D_{k,\ell}=P_{k,\ell}$ when $\ell =2, k$. Is it true that, for arbitrary $2\leq \ell \leq k$, $D_{k,\ell}$ is $P_{k,\ell}$ plus (possibly) some additional terms?

Comment: I made a small edit to reflect the fact that $a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_k x_k$ is a linear form, not a monomial. Further, by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ do you mean the $2$-adic integers or the field $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: The $a_i$ are all supposed to be in $\left\{0,1\right\}$, right?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: yes, exactly

Comment: If $\ell=1$, then the determinant is $0$ (at least for $k \geq 2$) since all of the $\alpha_j$ are $1$. But $P_{k,\ell} = x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Sorry, I forgot the $\ell\geq 2$ -- now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this true? Sage disagrees:

```
P.<a,b,c,d> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
xs = P.gens()
M = Matrix(P, [[xs[i] ** (1 + binomial(j, 1) + binomial(j,2)) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)])
M.determinant().factor()
```

returns

```
d * c * (c + d) * b * (b + d) * (b + c) * a * (a + d) * (a + c) * (a + b) * (a^3*b + a^2*b^2 + a*b^3 + a^3*c + b^3*c + a^2*c^2 + b^2*c^2 + a*c^3 + b*c^3 + a^3*d + b^3*d + a*b*c*d + c^3*d + a^2*d^2 + b^2*d^2 + c^2*d^2 + a*d^3 + b*d^3 + c*d^3)
```

This has all the right factors with $1$ or $2$ addends (which is no surprise), but the remaining degree-$4$ factor does not factor further as you want it to. For comparison, the product of the factors with $3$ addends should be

```
P.prod([P.sum(xs)-r for r in xs])
```

which is

```
a^3*b + a*b^3 + a^3*c + b^3*c + a*c^3 + b*c^3 + a^3*d + b^3*d + a*b*c*d + c^3*d + a*d^3 + b*d^3 + c*d^3
```

Generally, I think you can learn something about these polynomials from: [I. G. Macdonald, *Schur functions: Theme and variations*, Séminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire 1992, volume 28, page B28a](https://eudml.org/doc/119412) (specifically, the 7th variation, which does not assume much familiarity with the preceding ones). But do not expect explicit formulas beyond the $\ell = 2$ and $\ell = k$ cases.

Comment: @darjinberg: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

For a given $\sigma\in S_{k}$, the coefficient of $x_{\sigma(1)}^{\alpha_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_{\sigma(k)}^{\alpha_k}$ in $P_{k,l}$ is 1. So $D_{k,l}$ is $P_{k,l}$ plus (possibly) some additional terms.

Comment: Not sure I get your argument.

Comment: I mean you can uniquely construct $x_{\sigma(1)}^{\alpha_1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_{\sigma(k)}^{\alpha_k}$, in $ P_{k,\ell} = \prod_{1\leq a_1+\ldots+a_k\leq \ell} (a_1x_1+\ldots + a_kx_k)$

Comment: I still don't get it.